# How to loop in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an issue where I have duplicate elements in the input XML. Not sure how to loop it to get the value if the first element doesn't have a value. Please advise. In the input XML it shows two records for each Contract and Lastname. The first two elements in the DOCUMENT shows blank. How do I get the value using loop? If statement? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the input XML look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<MR>
    <MRCase>
        <ImageId>1542341</ImageId>
        <MRNumber/>
        <Claims/>
    </MRCase>
    <Document>
        <Contract/>
        <Lastname/>
        <SIUReferenceList/>
        <ClaimNoList/>
    </Document>
    <Document>
        <Contract>H11193004362</Contract>
        <Lastname>WESLEY</Lastname>
        <MRReferenceList>|201802380|201802380|</MRReferenceList>
        <MRNoList>|80489_E9OB_11</MRNoList>
    </Document> 
</MR>
```

Here's what I have done so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:env ="urn:envision">
    <xsl:template match="MR">       
        <xsl:element name="MR">
            <xsl:element name="MRCase"> 
                <xsl:element name ="ImageId">
                    <xsl:value-of select="MRCase/ImageId"/>
                </xsl:element>  
                <xsl:element name="Contract">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains('Contract')">
                            <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>                     
                            <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name ="Lastname">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Lastname"/>
                </xsl:element>             
            </xsl:element> 
        </xsl:element>   
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired output

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<MR>
    <MRCase>
        <ImageId>1542341</ImageId>
    </MRCase>
    <Document>
        <Contract>H11193004362</Contract>
        <Lastname>WESLEY</Lastname>
        <MRReferenceList>|201802380|201802380|</MRReferenceList>
        <MRNoList>|80489_E9OB_11</MRNoList>
    </Document> 
</MR>
```

Comment: so, you want to filter out the elements which doesn't have any text, right?

Comment: @Rubens Farias, the desired solution is to get the value from the element which has the value. There could be three <contract> elements and three <lastname> elements. Two don't have any text or value and the last one has . If lets say that is the case, I want to get the element that has the text or value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop - you just need to adjust your template match to filter out `Document` with empty child elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- templates matching unwanted elements -->

    <xsl:template match="MRNumber" />

    <xsl:template match="Claims" />

    <!-- takes care of that Document with empty child nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="Document[Contract = '' and Lastname = '' and SIUReferenceList = '' and ClaimNoList = '']" />

    <!-- end of unwanted elements -->

    <!-- the "good" Document -->
    <xsl:template match="Document[Contract != '' and Lastname != '' and SIUReferenceList != '' and ClaimNoList != '']">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- let identity transform take care of the rest -->    
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I really appreciate it. I'm going to try this option as well.

Comment: @Les Matching templates vs. for-each can be a little hard to wrap your head around at first but is very powerful and not as messy when transformations get bigger and requirements more complicated. Basically you can always start out with the so-called *identity transform* that copies everything and keep adding matching templates until you get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, it has both the for loop and the if statement you asked about. There may be a more efficient way to achieve what you want. I was able to test this in xsltFiddle here is the link in case you need to play round with it https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:env ="urn:envision">
<xsl:template match="MR">       
    <xsl:element name="MR">
        <xsl:element name="MRCase"> 
            <xsl:element name ="ImageId">
                <xsl:value-of select="MRCase/ImageId"/>
            </xsl:element>  
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:for-each select="Document">
            <xsl:element name="Document"> 
                <xsl:if test="Contract != ''">
                    <xsl:element name="Contract" ><xsl:value-of select="Contract"/></xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="Lastname"><xsl:value-of select="Lastname"/></xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="MRReferenceList" ><xsl:value-of select="MRReferenceList"/></xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="MRNoList" ><xsl:value-of select="MRNoList"/></xsl:element>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:element>   
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>   
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much on your suggestion. I'm going to try this and let you know.